# Java for loop exceeds limits. Android

Tags: java, android, debugging, for-loop, nullpointerexception

I'm doing a project in Android Studio and am getting a null pointer exception when I definitely shouldn't be. Here is the problem code:

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
boolean[][] cellClicked = new boolean[3][3];
boolean player1 = false;
boolean player2 = true;
boolean currentPlayer;
ImageView[][] cells = new ImageView[3][3];

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) throws NullPointerException{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    currentPlayer = player1;
    cells[0][0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_0);
    cells[0][1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_1);
    cells[0][2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_2);
    cells[1][0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_3);
    cells[1][1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_4);
    cells[1][2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_5);
    cells[2][0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_6);
    cells[2][1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_7);
    cells[2][2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cell_8);

    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; i < 3; j++) {
                setListeners(i, j);
            }
        }
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        throw new NullPointerException("cant access element");
    }

}
private void setListeners(int i, int j){
    final int row = i;
    final int col = j;
    cells[row][col].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!cellClicked[row][col]) {
                makeMove(cells[row][col], row, col);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the app, as soon as I navigate to PlayActivity, the app crashes. When I look at the log errors, it shows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: net.drmcb.tictactoe, PID: 29345
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.drmcb.tictactoe/net.drmcb.tictactoe.PlayActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
     at net.drmcb.tictactoe.PlayActivity.setListeners(PlayActivity.java:55)
     at net.drmcb.tictactoe.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:44)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

The lines the errors are referring to are 44: `setListeners(i, j);` and  55:

```
cells[row][col].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!cellClicked[row][col]) {
            makeMove(cells[row][col], row, col);
        }
    }
});
```

I commented out all the code in `makeMoves()` so that's not the problem.

In my for loops encasing the call to setListeners(), the `i < 3` part is highlighted and when I hover over it, it tells me "Condition 'i < 3' is always true"...

In attempting to debug this for the last several hours, I have the following questions:

Why does the for loop exceed it's `i < 3` conditional?

Why does any reference to `cells.length` or `cells[0].length` break the code?

Comment: this is not a good idea: ***catch(NullPointerException e)***

Comment: are those views ok? is the name right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not `Null Exception`, its an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
because you have a mistake in your inner `for loop`

`for(int j = 0; i < 3; j++) {`

note the **i<3** should be **j<3**

```
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your **j** was able to increment up to 3 because your i < 3 in

```
for(int j = 0; i < 3; j++) {
```

will always be true because i is 0.
As what Yazan said, just correct your i < 3 to j < 3 and it will be fine.

 This also tells us to properly name our variables to avoid this kind of problems.